# Prove that if H ∪ K is a subgroup of G...

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Suppose G is a group, with subgroups H and K.

Prove that if H ∪ K is a subgroup of G implies that H ⊆ K or K ⊆ H.

I'm not really sure how to start this, I can prove that H ∩ K is a subgroup but I don't know how to approach the union. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Please tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: Please search before asking.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been changed since I wrote this -- initially there was no requirement for $H$ or $K$ to be subgroups of $G$.

---

Unless I've misunderstood your question, what you have written is wrong. For example, take $G = \{0,1\}$ with the operation of addition modulo 2, $H = \{0\}$ and $K = \{1\}$. Then $H \cup K = G$ which is certainly a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Your choices of $G$ are not groups. 0 is not invertible in either. Further, subgroups cannot have empty intersection, since they both must contain the identity of the group.

Comment: Dammit, too much stuff on rings since doing groups! Ok, my first thing still works if you change to addition modulo 2, and the second can certainly be changed slightly to work. (Note that he's changed his question since I wrote my answer -- he didn't require $H$ or $K$ to be subgroups.)

Comment: Made those changes. Now the answer is correct for the time it was written.

Comment: Unfortunately, $K$ is still not a subgroup, since $1 + 1 \notin K$.

Comment: Please re-read my answer. That will clear up any confusion.